# What will happen if the single file is larger than a executor in a map operation in YARN - SPARK?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I'm working on a solution where driver program will read the xml file and from that i will take a HDFS file path and that will be read inside map operation.I have few questions here.
Since the map operation will be performed in containers (Containers will be allocated while starting the job ).

1. What is the single input file is greater than a executor. Since the file is not read in driver program it cannot allocate more resource? OR the application master will get more memory from resource manager?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using HDFS as FS ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the single input file is greater than a executor?

As the file is in HDFS, Spark will create **1 partition for 1 block in HDFS**. Every partitions will be processed in a Worker.

If file has many blocks which can't be computed at a time then spark make sure the pending partition will be computed once resources are free(after completing transformation with a stage).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Kishore. So Doesn't matter whether the file read is initiated from executor?

Comment: every Spark Executor will read one block of data only by default.

Answer (score 1):

Loaded file appears as RDD. RDD is combination of pieces so called partitions which are reside across cluster. Reading file is not problem but after transformation it can throw OOM exception depending on executor memory limitations. Because there can be some shuffle operations which will require transfer of partitions to one place. By default executor memory set to be 512MB. But for processing large amount of data set custom memory parameter.
 Spark reserves parts of that memory for cached data storage and for temporary shuffle data. Set the heap for these with the parameters spark.storage.memoryFraction (default 0.6) and spark.shuffle.memoryFraction (default 0.2). Because these parts of the heap can grow before Spark can measure and limit them, two additional safety parameters must be set: spark.storage.safetyFraction (default 0.9) and spark.shuffle.safetyFraction (default 0.8). Safety parameters lower the memory fraction by the amount specified. The actual part of the heap used for storage by default is 0.6 × 0.9 (safety fraction times the storage memory fraction), which equals 54%. Similarly, the part of the heap used for shuffle data is 0.2 × 0.8 (safety fraction times the shuffle memory fraction), which equals 16%. You then have 30% of the heap reserved for other Java objects and resources needed to run tasks. You should, however, count on only 20%.